# R mapply function row-wise for matching columns of two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes with the same column structure (just for simplification, as my dfs hold 40k+ observations).

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("mark", "peter", "lily"),
                  column1= c(1,2,3), 
                  column2 = c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("mark", "liam", "peter"), 
                  column1 = c(7,8,9), 
                  column2 = c(1,2,3))
```

What do you think would be the most elegant way to apply a function row-wise to matching columns of two dataframes but only their matching rownames?

In this example: `(df1$column1 + df1$column2)/df2$column2` should only be applied to the respective rows "mark" and "peter" in both dfs.

Comment: What about merging both data frames and then filtering for the rows you want the function to be applied on?

Comment: Also, it is a bit unclear as to what is you expected output, would you mind adding it?

Comment: Hey, sorry if I wasn't perfectly clear on my question. I want to automatically apply formulas to all of my rows that match in both dataframes. However, I did not know if I should merge them before or to directly apply functions taking row values of both dfs.

The output would be values coming from this formulas I applied into a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
library(dplyr)

df_combined<-df1%>%
  left_join(df2, by="name") %>%
  mutate(combined=(column1.x + column2.x)/column2.y) %>%
  filter(!is.na(combined)) %>%
  select(name,combined)

df1 %>% left_join(df_combined)
#>    name column1 column2 combined
#> 1  mark       1       4 5.000000
#> 2 peter       2       5 2.333333
#> 3  lily       3       6       NA

df2 %>% left_join(df_combined)
#>    name column1 column2 combined
#> 1  mark       7       1 5.000000
#> 2  liam       8       2       NA
#> 3 peter       9       3 2.333333
```

If you want to do it with a list of dataframes...

```
library(purrr)

df_list<-list(df1,df2)

add_match_column<-function(df){
  df %>% left_join(df_combined)
}

df_list_matched <-df_list %>%
  map(add_match_column)

df_list_matched[[1]]
#>    name column1 column2 combined
#> 1  mark       1       4 5.000000
#> 2 peter       2       5 2.333333
#> 3  lily       3       6       NA

df_list_matched[[2]]
#>    name column1 column2 combined
#> 1  mark       7       1 5.000000
#> 2  liam       8       2       NA
#> 3 peter       9       3 2.333333
```

Comment: This one works perfectly.
Is there perhaps also a way to transform this into a function so that I can use it on a list of dataframes? (With lapply() I guess, but I'm still learning how to make correct functions)

Comment: Good question! I like map from the purrr library. See edits above.

Comment: Brilliant, there is only one piece missing. I have 10 dfs (named by year), and would like to apply your df_combined script to 2 consecutive dfs in my list (i.e. df1 <- df2011, df2 <- df2012 and in the next "mutation" df1 <- df2012, df2 <- df2013 and so on...).

I tried to apply something like this:
```
function(i){
        myDist( myData[i,], myData[i+1,] )
    })
```
but I got stuck again

Answer (score 0):

A **base R** solution. First `merge` the data frames, then select the resulting columns with `grep`.

```
df_new <- merge(df1, df2, "name")

df_new
   name column1.x column2.x column1.y column2.y
1  mark         1         4         7         1
2 peter         2         5         9         3

df_new$calc <- apply(df_new[,-1], 1, function(a) 
  sum(a[grep("\\.x",names(a))]) / a[grep("2\\.y",names(a))])

df_new
   name column1.x column2.x column1.y column2.y     calc
1  mark         1         4         7         1 5.000000
2 peter         2         5         9         3 2.333333
```